# How can I return a simple "Access Denied" message during error catching instead of the whole error stack?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that goes though a list of servers and checks to see if the DNS entries are set to a specific value.

I am set an environment variable when I make the WMI call to catch any errors and both write them to screen and to a text file.  It is writing a truncated version of the error (which is what I want) on everything except "access denied".  On that error it dumps the entire stack.

My question is, how do I get the "access denied" error stack down to just reporting something like Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

What is strange is that when I run the script then just type $err and hit enter I get the following:

PS C:\myScripts> $err
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

When I try to Write-Host $err or Add-Content $err I get the whole error stack. (I can post it if you want...just trying to save space.)

script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

Clear-Content C:\myScripts\iofiles\dns.txt
$servers = Get-Content "C:\myScripts\iofiles\hosts.txt" 

#Set the DNS values to check for
$newDNS1 = "1.1.1.1" #placeholder value 
$newDNS2 = "1.1.1.2" #placeholder value 


ForEach($server in $servers){
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Checking" $server -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $server -filter "ipenabled='true'" -ea "SilentlyContinue" -ev err
    $primaryDNS = $wmi.DNSServerSearchOrder[0]
    $secondaryDNS = $wmi.DNSServerSearchOrder[1]

    if ($err.count -gt 0) {
        Add-Content C:\myScripts\iofiles\dns.txt "$server - $err"
        Write-Host "Error on $name $err" -ForegroundColor Red
    }else{

        if ($primaryDNS -ne $newDNS1) {
        Add-Content C:\myScripts\iofiles\dns.txt "$server - Primary DNS incorrectly set - $primaryDNS"
        Write-Host "Primary DNS incorrectly set: " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline; Write-Host $primaryDNS -ForegroundColor Red
        }else{
            Write-Host "Primary DNS Correct" -ForegroundColor Green

        }if ($secondaryDNS -ne $newDNS2) {
        Add-Content C:\myScripts\iofiles\dns.txt "$server - Secondary DNS incorrectly set - $secondaryDNS"
        Write-Host "Secondary incorrectly set: " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline; Write-host $secondaryDNS -ForegroundColor Red
        }else{
            Write-Host "Secondary DNS correct" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
        }
}#END ForEach
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you suffer from a DCOM related error:

[0x80070005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394603(v=vs.85).aspx) – E_ACCESS_DENIED: Access denied by DCOM security.

> The user does not have remote access to the computer through DCOM.
>   Typically, DCOM errors occur when connecting to a remote computer with
>   a different operating system version.
>
> Give the user Remote Launch and Remote Activation permissions in
>   dcomcnfg. Right-click My Computer-> Properties Under COM Security,
>   click "Edit Limits" for both sections. Give the user you want remote
>   access, remote launch, and remote activation. Then go to DCOM Config,
>   find "Windows Management Instrumentation", and give the user you want
>   Remote Launch and Remote Activation. For more information, see
>   Connecting Between Different Operating Systems

Comment: This attempts to address why OP is encountering the error but does not answer OP's posed question, which is 'how can I just get "access denied" as a recorded output instead of the entire access denied error stack?"